# What if the swift code is correct but wrong bank account number?

Tags: payment, swift

I ended up paying to an account number which i am not sure is of the receipient. However other details like swift code and bank name etc were correct. The party hasn't received the payment. I should have gotten the payment back???

Comment: You say you aren't sure whether the account number was that of the intended recipient. Can you verify that one way or another?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you end up paying to an account number you are not sure of is the right one?

Answer (score 2):

If the account number is not of beneficiary, but is a valid account number, it would get credited to someone else account.

If the account number was invalid, it would be returned. This takes few weeks at times.

Best is raise a query with your bank saying beneficiary is claiming non receipt of funds (BCNR). Your bank would investigate with beneficiary bank and confirm if transfer was made and give evidence or track the refund.